# Why is `[1, "a"] :: [forall a. Show a => a]` not allowed?

Tags: haskell, polymorphism, typeclass, existential-type, higher-rank-types

In my (might incorrect) understanding, following two lists should be equivalent:

```
[1, "a"] :: [forall a. Show a => a]

data V = forall a. Show a => V a
[V 1, V "a"] :: [V]
```

However, the first one is not accepted but the second one works fine (with `ExistentialQuantification`).

If the first list doesn't exist, what would be the type in the blank of `map V :: ??? -> [V]`? What type mechanism enforces the existence of the wrapper?

Comment: This has always bugged me. I hate that `[show 1, show "a"]` and `map show [1, "a"]` aren't the same.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your understanding is not right. A big part of the problem is that the traditional existential quantification syntax you've used is pretty confusing to anyone who isn't thoroughly familiar with it. I therefore strongly recommend that you use GADT syntax instead, which also has the benefit of being strictly more powerful. The easy thing to do is just to enable `{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}`. While we're at it, let's turn on `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`, because I hate wondering what `forall` means in any given spot. Your `V` definition means exactly the same thing as

```
data V where
  V :: forall a . Show a => a -> V
```

We can actually drop the explicit `forall` if we like:

```
data V where
  V :: Show a => a -> V
```

So the `V` data constructor is a function that takes something of *any* showable type and produces something of type `V`. The type of `map` is pretty restrictive:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

All the elements of the list passed to `map` have to have the same type. So the type of `map V` is just

```
map V :: Show a => [a] -> [V]
```

Let's get back to your first expression now:

```
[1, "a"] :: [forall a. Show a => a]
```

Now what this actually says is that `[1, "a"]` is a list, each of whose elements has type `forall a . Show a => a`. That is, if I provide any `a` that's an instance of `Show`, each element of the list should have that type. This is simply not true. `"a"` does not, for example, have type `Bool`. There's yet another problem here; the type `[forall a . Show a => a]` is "impredicative". I don't understand the details of what that means, but loosely speaking you've stuck a `forall` in the argument of a type constructor other than `->`, and that's not allowed. GHC might suggest that you enable the `ImpredicativeTypes` extension, but this really doesn't work right, so you shouldn't. If you want a list of existentially quantified things, you need to wrap them up first in existential datatypes or use a specialized existential list type. If you want a list of universally quantified things, you need to wrap them up first (probably in newtypes).